# Create PDF button not enabled in quote

Tags: quote, quote-template

In production I can't use create pdf button as it shows 'there must be an active template to create pdf'. I checked quote templates but there is no template available when I try to create new template it ask for existing one (there is no existing template). Can anybody tell what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Output Template. The the most recent guide to Output Builder that I have found is 'FinancialForce-Output-Builder-User-Guide-V13.0-SP-2', however I cannot find the link for it anymore. It should help since it has examples, so I would recommend getting in touch with FF support and ask them to send it to you.

Comment: I raised a case to salesforce support and I am able to make it work now the problem is someone deleted the metadata while deploying. They suggest me to disable the quote and enable it again after doing this I am able to create new template.

Comment: We use another object (we call ours SOW's, which stands for Statement of Work) for the metadata. That then uses an apex class to pull the metadata into an object called Client Proposal which has the button that calls Output Builder. This enables us to have multiple boiler plate SOW's that always stay the same and are only editable by our system admins. The Client Proposal can then have rich text fields that our sales team can edit as they see fit. Our Output Builder then supplies the styling and pulls the dynamic data into the final Output from fields on the quote object.

Comment: @SankarGanesh You can post that as answer it would help others facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after reading Sankar Ganesh's response I logged out and logged back in and the PDF option was available. There is some caching that happens with Lightning that classic didn't have.